# How to access Secret Manager in Cloud Function node.js10?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-secret-manager

I've been working on this for 2 days, very frustrated with the progress, any guidance on what is possibly wrong with my understanding/code/approach would be highly appreciated!

I'm trying to get version value from secret mananger using node.js, the script below works fine on GCE, but whenever I run it on Cloud function it fails.

```
// My script on GCE, it works fine
const { SecretManagerServiceClient } = require('@google-cloud/secret-manager');
const secretManagerServiceClient = new SecretManagerServiceClient();
const name = 'projects/moonhome/secrets/moonFirstSecret/versions/latest';

testSecretManager = async () => {
  const [version] = await secretManagerServiceClient.accessSecretVersion({ name });
  const payload = version.payload.data.toString();
  console.debug(`Payload: ${payload}`);
};
testSecretManager();
```

```
// My index.js on Cloud Function
const { SecretManagerServiceClient } = require('@google-cloud/secret-manager');
const secretManagerServiceClient = new SecretManagerServiceClient();
const name = 'projects/moonhome/secrets/moonFirstSecret/versions/latest';

testSecretManager = async () => {
  const [version] = await secretManagerServiceClient.accessSecretVersion({ name });
  const payload = version.payload.data.toString();
  console.debug(`Payload: ${payload}`);
};

exports.helloHttp = (req, res) => {
  testSecretManager();
  res.send("noooo1");
};
```

```
// One of many versions of packaga.json I tried on Cloud function
{
  "dependencies": {
      "@google-cloud/secret-manager": {
        "version": "3.1.0",
        "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@google-cloud/secret-manager/-/secret-manager-3.1.0.tgz",
        "integrity": "sha512-/9IOWEhKAz/r3kSyp16kjudELkEJSRhwFfzukKbzQehVRZ3RceNDzjn+Rti1TivODJHEEIBZVsQFsKp7cLfUgQ==",
        "requires": {
            "google-gax": "^2.1.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below are my questions:

1. I noticed there is a [list](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/nodejs-system-packages#requesting_a_package) of available system packages on node.js runtime in Cloud Function, so I am wondering if that's the reason. I already filed a request to add `@google-cloud/secret-manager` to node.js runtime. However, there is a example in the Cloud Function documentation where `escape-html` is used which also is absent from that list. My question is, **should I request to add the secret-manager package to node.js runtime in my case?**
2. Since Cloud Function needs an event trigger, I also tried to wrap this `testSecretManager` with a simple function to handle http request and tested it at the endpoint in my browser. The simple function itself works fine, but whenever I insert anything related to secret manager into that function, either the function fails or the page shows it `Error: could not handle the request`. My question is, **do I have to wrap `testSecretManager` with an HTTP request or any other event handling function to trigger my target function in Cloud Function?**
3. I am very confused with the `package.json` file on Cloud function, when I use secret-manager in GCE, the `package-lock.json` has 600+ lines, so I tried coping these lines to `package.json` on Cloud Function, but it does not work.....my question is, **what should I include in package.json when all I want is just the `@google-cloud/secret-manager` package?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You’re confusing system packages and Node packages. System packages are installed on the host machine (e.g. `apt-get install`). NPM packages are installed into Node (e.g. `npm install`). **You should not request secret manager be added to system packages.**
2. You’re function is mixing sync and async. Since your `testSecretManager` function is a sync, you need to preface with `await` when you call it in `helloHttp`. Then you’ll need to mark `helloHttp` as async. If that doesn’t work, please copy and paste the exact error message and stacktrace.
3. `package.json` and `package-lock.json` are separate files with separate syntaxes. **You should not copy data from the lockfile into your package file.** Here’s [an example](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-secret-manager/blob/master/samples/package.json#L17) you can copy:

   ```
    "dependencies": {
      "@google-cloud/secret-manager": "^3.1.0"
    },
   ```

Comment: it worked! Thank you very much!!!! Now I will try to get the secret to print somewhere, the console.debug() did not leave anything in the logs.

Comment: Again, thank you so much! I learned a lot! now the async is fixed, the secret simply shows on the page now.